# Running custom scripts in a custom container while running a sagemaker training job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am currently in the process of setting up a custom sagemaker container to run training jobs on Sagemaker and have succeeded in doing so. However, I am a bit confused over this question which is currently bugging me and is definitely something that I need to consider in the future

1. Is it possible to run custom scripts on a custom container when declaring a sagemaker training job?

My current understanding when it comes to creating a custom sagemaker image is that I create a train file that gets executed when running a training job, but I could never find documentation on whether is it possible to overwrite this and run a training script (but using the same custom container), like how we run training jobs using in-built algorithms. Is it the case that for custom algorithms we are restricted by this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question (can you make an example please?), specially when you say

> like how we run training jobs using in-built algorithms

But basically you can do whatever you want in your container, as probably you already did, you have a proper `train` file in your container, which is the one that sagemaker calls as the entrypoint. In that file you can call external script (which are in your container too) and also pass parameters to your container (see how for example hyperparameters are passed). There is a quite clear documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/docker-containers-create.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Apologies for the confusion earlier. Anyway, in situations where we utilise containers that are provided by AWS, there is the option of adding your own training script to those containers. 

For custom containers, I am aware of the need to define the train script, but when looking at the api documentation, there is an option to link it to additional dependencies, hence, I was just wondering whether is there a way to circumvent this "train" script limitation.

Comment: I still do not understand what is the limitation you are talking about.. can you please add both examples (option in container provided by AWS and option to link to additional dependencies in your custom container) editing your question?

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your reply and apologies for the late reply. Found what I needed in the end here. 
https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/advanced_functionality/custom-training-containers/framework-container

Comment: I'm just starting something like this.. do you have any steps to follow to acheive the same like 1. how to create the ecr image 2. how to use the ecr container created, in our notebooks to create pipelines for different models? where each pipeline will have their own train script...

Comment: @Selva take a look at my repo: https://github.com/rokopi-byte/TFSagemakerDetection